# Is there a reference that gives lots of linux distribution coverage?

Tags: linux-distro

I'm building an application that needs to run on as many linux distributions as possible. I've got the thing running well enough, but I need to put on the finishing touches like dealing with service/init.d scripts and initrd/initramfs/dracut setups.

So I was wondering if there was some place that had a list of distros and what I'd have to do to make a new initr* and what I'd have to do to include a start/stop script that would get coverage for the most distributions possible.

Anybody know of such a thing?
Maybe this is a superuser question, but I figured programmers would know reference for this type of thing better.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your startup as a systemd unit file and when it's compiled the unit file should be installed in systemd. Most newer distros already use systemd.

Comment: ahhh, I guess I should have mentioned, the goal is to run on all sorts of distributions, not just the newer ones or the systemd ones.